# Why does 'allowing y to move more' change the value of this integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the integral:
$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_{|y|}^1(x+y)^2dxdy
$$

The domain of integration is the triangle described by $|y|\leq x\leq 1$.

I've drawn this domain of integration and thought that if instead of letting $-1\leq y \leq 1$, I plugged $-100 \leq y \leq 100$, I'd get the same result, as the figure drawn in the plane is the same.

But this is not the case. Why does this happen?

Also, what's an easy way to calculate it? I just expanded the square and separated the integrals on the intervals $y<0, y\geq 0$, but I wanted a more elegant way.

Comment: If you change the range of $y$ in that way, the region is the same, but if you just plug in the values on the integral limits you would be doing something different. You would be even integrating some negative values, because when $y=100$ the inner integral goes backwards.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The integral limits don't really know about your inequality $|y|\le x\le 1$, so, for example, when $y=100$, the inner integral reads $\int_100^1=-\int_1^100$. That is not what you want to do, of course. You would like the inner interval of integration to be empty when $y=100$, and the formula doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calculate
$$
\int_{-2}^{2} \int_{|y|}^{1} f(x, y)\, dx\, dy
$$
formally, you integrate over the *entire* shaded region in the diagram, not just the darker shaded region. (In the lighter triangles, $1 \leq |y|$, so limits on the inner integral are from a larger number to a smaller number. Integrating from $-100$ to $100$ has an entirely similar effect.)

Regarding your second question, if you change the order of integration, the original integral becomes a single "standard" integral
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{|y|}^{1} f(x, y)\, dx\, dy
  = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-x}^{x} f(x, y)\, dy\, dx.
$$

Alternatively, you can integrate using the antiderivative formulas (with $k \geq 0$ an integer)
$$
\int |y|^{2k}\, dy = \int y^{2k}\, dy = \frac{y^{2k+1}}{2k+1},\qquad
\int |y|^{2k+1}\, dy = \int y^{2k}|y|\, dy = \frac{y^{2k+1}|y|}{2k+2}.
$$

[image: Integrating over a plane region from larger to smaller bounds]